# onclick attribute can't find Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, dom-events

I can't manage to link my Javascript function to my 'onclick' html attribute in the span tag.
I keep getting the error:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: closeAndRefresh is not defined" "at
> HTMLSpanElement.onclick"

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="error">
    <div id="errorMessage">
        <span onclick="closeAndRefresh();">&#10006;</span>
        <p id="message">
            <?php echo $confirmationMessage ?>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    function closeAndRefresh() {
        <?php $visibility = 'hidden' ?>
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
</script>
```

I'll also add a screenshot of my code:

[image]

Comment: Ofcourse that lower than sign was not the problem ;)

Comment: Did you try putting the inline script above the HTML in the web page?

Comment: try to wrap your function inside window onload event or better use event listener rather than on click

Comment: @MaximDelaet Include your script before your HTML code as your function should be defined before its reference in html

Comment: I think there is some syntax issue with the first line in the function. when i commented out that line, it worked fine.

Comment: [Edit] The picture code into your question! A picture add Nothing here!

Comment: @MaximDelaet are you afrikaans dude?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Your script is after your HTML. Include it before html so that your function is defined

```js
function closeAndRefresh(){
  
        window.location.reload(true);
}
```

```html
<span onclick="closeAndRefresh();">&#10006;</span>
```

Comment: Including the <scipt> </script> tags before the html tags resolved this for me! Thanks dude. I always though the script tags go within the <head> tags, which is inherently inside the html tags... Learn something new every day (y)

Answer (score 1):

If you have recently added the function to your javascript code, consider clearing the browser's cache, in order to force it reload the javascript code. To check if this is the problem, on your browser show the source html code, find the line where the javascript code is included, and click on it; it will show you the javascript source code the browser is currently using, that may be out of date. Also, as mentioned by others, make sure you include the javascript code before you reference it.

Comment: This one helped in my case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the script `function closeAndRefresh()` in the head tag of your html page.

Maybe the html page is not able to load the script when you write it inside the body.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you reference the function correctly and also try putting the script above or below as it seems to be `function` not recognized.